# How would I position my logo to overlap the menu below and not be clipped?

Tags: html, css

I have a logo that sits just above my menu, but I would like it to drop slightly into the menu div without being cut off. In other words, I intentionally want it to display slightly inside the menu.

I have tried using relative positioning with an index above the div below, but still, it does not work. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

The demo site is here:
http://goo.gl/KXy2Ye

Comment: Don't post a link to your site. Instead, post the code in question here and possible a live demo at JSFiddle.net or Codepen.io

Comment: Please post the relevant code or recreate the problem in something like a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Answer (score 2):

Take off `overflow: hidden` from `.avada-row`

Answer (score 0):

Your class .avada-row has inline styling overflow:hidden. Remove the inline styling and plz try the following..

```
.avada-row{
overflow:visible;
}
```

Comment: this will not work as it is overridden by inline css

Comment: Thank you Binita - that was exactly it!

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="avada-row" style="margin-top:0px;margin-bottom:0px; overflow:hidden;">
</div>
```

You will have to remove overflow:hidden, and adjust the margin-bottom

Comment: Thanks. It was just the overflow that needed to be visible.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, take out the style "overflow:hidden" on the "avada-row" div.

Secondly, you'll want to give the "header" header and "small-nav" div "position:relative" and a proper "z-index". "header" should have a larger z-index then "small-nav". The css should look something like this:

```
#header { position:relative; z-index:10; }
#small-nav { position:relative; z-index:5; }
```

The trick is to target the parent divs that are on the same level when you are using positioning and z-index. If you target "avada-row" and "header" instead, it won't work because they are not on the same level. Hope that helps!